# Is it possible to pass a boolean to a directive and trigger something if that boolean changes without $watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6, angular-directive

I was hoping to be able to do something similar to the following simplified example:

```
class ButtonController {
  set isFoo(value) {
    console.log(value);
    // do something here
  }
}

angular.module('myApp', []).directive('mButton', () => {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controller: ButtonController,
    controllerAs: 'button',
    template: '<button class="btn" type="button">Blah</button>',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      isFoo: '='
    }
  };
});
```

and call the directive like:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <m-button is-foo="true"></m-button>
</div>
```

preview: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrWRVr?editors=1010

However, this generates a `$compile:nonassign` error so to fix, I could do this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="foo=true">
  <m-button is-foo="foo"></m-button>
</div>
```

preview: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VexweM?editors=1010

But I want to be able to pass the boolean directly as shown in the previous markup. Is this not possible? Do I really need to do something like the following if I want to pass the boolean directly?

```
class ButtonController {
  set isFooWatcher(value) {
    console.log(value);
    // do something here
  }
}

angular.module('myApp', []).directive('mButton', () => {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controller: ButtonController,
    controllerAs: 'button',
    template: '<button class="btn" type="button">Blah</button>',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      isFoo: '='
    },
    link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(() => ctrl.isFoo, () => {
        ctrl.isFooWatcher = ctrl.isFoo;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

preview: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QymxrZ?editors=1010

Comment: isFoo: '@' ? makes is-foo="true" as well as is-foo="{{var}}" possible

Comment: I can't use `@` because sometimes the value might be `true` sometimes it might be a model and it needs to be two-way bound.

Comment: actually, maybe I can get away without it being two-way bound in this instance.... haha. sometimes it really does help to have someone pull you back a bit. thanks! although, I then need to coerce all truthy/falsey values to the relevant boolean which isn't ideal

Answer (score 1):

Randomly figured this out today... the problem was that I had a setter for the property but not a getter! The following works:

```
class ButtonController {
  set isFoo(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this._isFoo = value;
  }

  get isFoo() {
    return this._isFoo;
  }
}

angular.module('myApp', []).directive('mButton', () => {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controller: ButtonController,
    controllerAs: 'button',
    template: '<button class="btn" type="button">Blah</button>',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      isFoo: '='
    }
  };
});
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxrZWe?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `&` one-way binding with little changes:

```
class ButtonController {
  set isFoo(get) {
    console.log( get() );
    // do something here
  }
}

angular.module('myApp', []).directive('mButton', () => {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controller: ButtonController,
    controllerAs: 'button',
    template: '<button class="btn" type="button">Blah</button>',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      isFoo: '&'
    }
  };
});
```

The advantage is that you can pass either an explicit boolean `true` or a model `myValue` containing the boolean. Or even an expression such as:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <m-button is-foo="someCondition && !data.invalid"></m-button>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought this might be the answer I was looking for but `is-foo` could be a model whose value changes and I need to know when it changes. Seems the setter doesn't get called if an `&` attr value changes... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyrwoM?editors=1010

Comment: @jjenzz indeed. I'm actually not familiar with this setter syntax so sorry if that doesn't help. You'd need a watcher but I guess that's what you want to avoid, although this setter looks like a watcher to me. A very tricky option would be to precompile your directive to replace the is-foo attribute by some ng-init or another king of watcher but I really don't see the point rather than an explicit watcher.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include either a

```
scope: {
    value1 : '&'
    value2 : '='
}
```

& : use the value as a string

= : use the value as a pointer to the value is scope

= is really nice as you don't have this crazy string in your DOM and when you update the value in the parent controller it will update in the directive automagically.

Or you can include it in a link function you can read about these in the docs.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive